# Understanding closure scope in Python

Tags: python, sorting, scope, closures

This is example from Bratt Slatkin's book

```
def sort_priority(values,   group):
    def helper(x):
        if  x   in  group:
            return  (0, x)
        return  (1, x)
    values.sort(key=helper)
```

Furthermore they gave these values

```
numbers =   [8, 3,  1,  2,  5,  4,  7,  6]
group   =   {2, 3,  5,  7}
sort_priority(numbers,  group)
print(numbers)
```

And we have

```
[2, 3,  5,  7,  1,  4,  6,  8]
```

I do not understand this example.Why do we have return two times and what does helper function actually do?

Comment: There are two places that the code can return, but a function always returns only once!

Comment: Please be more specific with what *exactly* don't you understand

Comment: @alfasin Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read the function as:

```
def helper(x):
    if x in group:
        return (0, x)
    else:
        return (1, x)
```

Or, more concisely,

```
def helper(x):
    return (x not in group, x)
```

The intuition behind this is that `sort` accepts a `key` callback which is called on each element. For each element, `helper` is invoked which returns a tuple (could be either `(0, x)` or `(1, x)` depending on whether `x` exists in the VIP list).

You should understand that tuples are sorted based on multiple predicates, meaning both items in the tuples are considered when deciding the order of elements. This would imply that elements for which group returns `(0, x)` will be ordered first compared to those returning `(1, x)` because `0 < 1`.

After this, we have two groups, those with first element `0` and those with first element `1`. All `0` group elements will come first, but the order of those elements depends on the second item in the tuples - `x`. And similar for `1` group elements.

---

For your input:

```
Group0: [2, 3, 5, 7]
Group1: [8, 1, 4, 6]

Ordering within Group0: [2, 3, 5, 7]
Ordering within Group1: [1, 4, 6, 8]

Overall ordering: [Group0, Group1]

Result:  [2, 3, 5, 7,    1, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we have return two times?

This has nothing to do with closures or nested functions.

```
def helper(x):
    if  x  in  group:
        return  (0, x)
    return  (1, x)
```

Can be written as

```
def helper(x):
    if  x   in  group:
        return  (0, x)
    else:        
        return  (1, x)
```

Either way, the return value depends on what the `if` statement is evaluated to.
If it is `True` then `(0, x)` will be returned. If it is `False` then `(1, x)` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first `return` statement is within the `if` block. In python whenever a function encounters a return statement, the execution is handed back to the caller
In your example, the two returns are just a shortcut way to avoid if else statements. When a particular value is in the group, `(0,x)` is returned and if the `if` condition is not satisfied, then `(1,x)` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit easier to understand the code when it's written without nested functions:

```
def helper(x):
    global group
    if x in group:
        return 0, x
    return 1, x


def sort_priority(values):
    values.sort(key=helper)


numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = {2, 3, 5, 7}
sort_priority(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Now it's easy to see that `sort_priority()` simply sorts the values by calling the `helper` function which creates an order by assigning a value to each `x`.

When the `helper` function is called with a value that's in `group` - it gets "lower" priority (zero) while if the value is not in `group`, it gets higher priority (one).

A closer look at `helper` indeed shows:

```
def helper(x):
    global group
    if x in group:
        return 0, x  # <-- we're in the `if` so `x` gets zero 
    return 1, x      # <-- if we got here it means we didn't get into the `if` so `x` gets one
```

So by using the `helper` as a `key` function in the sorting, we'll get and ordered lists which puts the items that are in `group` first and only then the items that are not in `group`:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8]
             ^
            The first item that is not in group
```

Answer (score -1):

It is more obvious for me to use `sorted(values)` function instead of `values.sort()`, otherwise it is little ambiguous "what is returned?", "how actually helper is used?".

```
def sort_priority(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return (0, x)
        return (1, x)
    sorted_values = sorted(values, key=helper)
    return sorted_values

numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = {2, 3, 5, 7}
print('Sorted Numbers List: ', sort_priority(numbers, group))
```

Of course after `sorted()` is used, sorted list returned it explicitly.